# Are memory pool and transaction pool the same thing?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, terminology, mempool

As far I know, unconfirmed transactions are stored in the *memory pool*. However, in [the Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_rules), I see a data structure called *transaction pool*. Are they the same thing or not? Also for the orphan transactions, as far as I know they are stored in data structure called *orphan pool*, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is referring to what is now called the mempool.

The wiki is unmaintained, and contains mostly outdated or incomplete information. I would suggest you use the bitcoin.org documentation instead.

Comment: And what about the orphan transactions? Are they in a separate data structure called orphan pool?

Comment: Yes, as I explained here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/54322/208